# Any surviving green eyed Kaminoans in Star Wars Canon or Expanded Universe?

Tags: star-wars, aliens, star-wars-legends

I read in Star Wars that the species known as the Kaminoans created a [caste system based on eye-color](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kaminoan/Legends). At the bottom of this system were those born with green eyes who were viewed as such a threat to Kaminoan society that they were killed shortly after being born. What I want to know is if there are any stories in the Star Wars Canon or the Expanded Universe about a Kaminoan with green eyes surviving extermination somehow.

Comment: At least [none Wookipedia knew of](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Kaminoans)